# Concatenate DataRows into one big text file

Tags: powershell

For the following script, it creates a file with all the rows returned by the query. However, each row is following by a *line break*. Is it a way join the rows without the line break?

```
$sql = "select .... from ...." 
$r = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance xxx $sql
$name = "test.txt"
$r | % { $_[0] >> $name }
```

**Update:**
a testable example:

```
$sql = "select 'a' C union all select 'b' union all select 'c' " 
$r = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance yoursever $sql
$name = "c:\temp\test.txt"
$r | % { $_[0] >> $name }
```

expect

> abc

instead of

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: I have no idea what `$xml` is. Provide a working sample.

Comment: Just fixed it. it should be `$r`.

Comment: Avoid redirectors in powershell. That's the old way. What happends if you use ex. `$r | % { $_[0] } | Set-Content $name` ?

Comment: It behave the same. I've updated the question with a testable script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with a stream, then it will also be fast!

```
$sql = "select 'a' C union all select 'b' union all select 'c' " 
$r = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance yoursever $sql
$name = "c:\temp\test.txt"

$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "$name"
$r | % { $stream.Write($_[0]) } #Write() as opposed to WriteLine()
$stream.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The datarows are multiple objects, so saving them foreach will write each value to their own line. Collect the values and join them before saving, like:

```
($r | % { $_[0] }) -join '' >> $name
```

Comment: This works. However, the SQL result may be 100MB big. Is it a way to do it by piping?